Keyboard Utility: Customize Logitec MX Keys backlight without the Options+ app
Using Logitec MX Keyboard without Logitech's Options+ app. It works fine, but I can't control backlight on-duration.
There are key-mapping utilities, but I can't find one for backlight control. There is no key for this setting and I don't know of a shortcut, either.
Can I control backlight on-duration with an app other than Options+? I don't want to install it.
PS: When/How did functions like these become so locked down?

@jaume Edit reads well, thanks!
